# Confusion on a proposition of an algebra book

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have the following propostion from my algebra book:

Prop 2.42. Let $f: X \to Y $ be a bijection. Suppose $A \subseteq X $ and $B \subseteq Y $. Assume that $f(A) \subseteq B $ and $f^{-1}(B) \subseteq A $. Then $f(A) = B $ and the corresponding $\mathbf{corestriction } $ $F$ of the restriction $f |_A $ to $B$ is a bijection $
F : A \to B $  and $F^{-1} : B \to A $ is the correstriction of $(f^{-1})|_B$ to $A$.

This is the proposition which I found confusing. What is the definition of corestriction? the book never defines this term.

Comment: Rather than restricting the domain to $A$ (as in the restriction), in this case you restrict the codomain to $B$. Ive never actually heard the term used before though.

Comment: The first part is just set equality so take an $x\in f(A)$ and show that $x$ is also in $B$. Then go the other way. Take $x\in B$ and show it's also in $f(A)$. The second part just says if you restrict the original function to the set $A$, then it maps bijectively to $B$. Drwaing some pictures might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All they mean is the following: The function $f|_A : A \to Y$ has image contained in $B$. Thus, we can restrict the codomain, and write the function as $f|_A : A \to B$. Since we're restricting the codomain, I guess we can call it "corestricting" the function (to be honest, I've never heard this term either).